# Couchbase bucket insert behaves asynchronously java

Tags: java, asynchronous, couchbase, nosql

I am using **JsonDocument inserted = bucket.insert(doc);** on couchbase-server-enterprise_4.1.0-ubuntu14.04_amd64.

What exactly happening is, I trigger this *insert* command and on success of this I trigger the *Select* command on same document. This *Select* command doesn't returns the update entries instead returns the old ones only. When I am using debugger before *Select* (wait for some seconds after *insert* and then call *Select*) it works totally fine. So i think insert behaves in async manner, not sure.

Other thing i have checked is *upsert* instead of *insert*, it is also not working. However when I do *bucket.replace(doc)* and then call *Select*, it returns the updated results. I have tried explicitly using the *bucket.async().insert(doc)* and the using *toBlocking().single()* on it, this also fails.

Is the issue with *insert/upsert* or I am doing something wrong.

Below is some of my code snippet ::

```
@Override
public T save(T entity, String username) {

String id = generateId(entity);

JsonObject data = JsonObject.fromJson(getContent(entity));
data.removeKey(ID);
data.put(TYPE, klass.getSimpleName());
data.put(CREATED_AT, new Date().getTime());
data.put(CREATED_BY, username);
data.put(MODIFIED_AT, new Date().getTime());
data.put(MODIFIED_BY, username);
data.put(ACTIVE, true);

T persistedEntity = getEntity(bucket.insert(JsonDocument.create(id, data)));

return persistedEntity;

}

@Override
public List findAll() {
Statement query = selectAll().where(typeExpression()).orderBy(Sort.desc(x(CREATED_AT)));
return getEntities(query);
}

protected AsPath selectAll() {
return Select.select("meta().id, *").from(i(bucket.name()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

N1QL queries can run with varying degrees of consistencies, unlike key/value operations which are always consistent (you "read-your-own-writes").

So there is a slight delay between an insertion and the indexer catching up to it. If you execute a N1QL query by default it will return what's the current state of the indexer, so if it is still indexing your document you won't see the update.

Try executing the query with a `ScanConsistency` of `REQUEST_PLUS`, where you do the `bucket().query(...)`:

```
N1qlQuery n1qlQuery = N1qlQuery.simple(
    selectStatement, //that's the Statement query in your example
    N1qlParams
        .build()
        .consistency(ScanConsistency.REQUEST_PLUS)
);
```

This will instruct N1QL to wait for the indexer to finish indexing pending mutations.

Comment: Simon, I think it's not that issue; 'Select' returns 'old' one... that is, not indexing problem.

'Select' finds the 'original' document', but its 'content' is old one... it may not view query stale problem. :)